# Inline element appended with jQuery goes on new line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I was trying to build a responsive form, that i would then have used in some of my websites, but got stuck with a little detail. I want to enable input validation with javascript, so when a user inserts an invalid input in an input text box, I want an error message to pop up by the box, with an IMG tag at the right of the input and a DIV tag under the input. I achieve this by appending (jQuery) these elements to the input's parent element, which is a LABEL.

Here is the base input:

```
<label for="errore"><span class="title">Errato</span><input type="text" name="errore" id="errore" size="30" maxlength="30" value="Cliccami e poi esci"/></label>
```

and here is how i append the elements.

```
$(this).parent().append("<img class='error' src='css/img/cross.png' alt='error' /><span class='error'>Input non valido.</span>");
```

so, if the user then inputs a correct input and exits the INPUT tag, the error message should disappear. I do this by removing the elements like this:

```
$(this).parent().find("*.error").remove();
```

And it works just fine. But, if i follow this sequence: Wrong input, exit element, error message, correct input, exit element, error message disappears, wrong input, exit element, error message reappears BUT the image is on new line! And that's only in chrome. Dunno why. It seems to depend on the element next to the IMG element, if it's an inline element it works fine both the 1st and 2nd time, if it's a block element it works fine the 1st time and wrong the 2nd.

So, my problem is the image element, i don't want it to go on a new line, but I want the element next to it to be a block element.

I know this may be not so clear, so I'll include my example.

[form example (JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/RedKnight91/CCEn2/4/)

in the example it's sufficient to enter and then exit the input with the title "Errato", to add the error message, and then enter and exit to remove it. So if you do that 3 times you should get the wrong error message.

it looks like the image is going to display: block or something, 'cause the effect is that, but if you check the css on the browser's console, it's actually display: inline.

If you need more details, feel free to ask.

Comment: better do a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or screenshot instead of letting us download a file

Comment: thanks a lot for the suggestion, I didn't know such a cool service existed! Here you go -> [link](http://jsfiddle.net/CCEn2/1/)

Comment: You should consider uploading your error image somewhere and change `src='css/img/check.png'` to the image URL.

Comment: That's not necessary to see the error, but ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this way to solve your problem. I think you only put the input field inside the label element to have a better way of adding and removing the infotext. So this might be a solution, too.

Changes I made:
in CSS: removed span element wrapping the labeltext

```
label.title{ font-weight:bold; display:block; margin-top:5px; }
```

in Javascript: Add the two info elements directly after the input field and remove the next two siblings of this input field with class ".error".
Also changed the span holding the errormessage to a div element.

[I also forked your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/junior87/FsUpG/)

Comment: Just perfect! But why was mine not working? Maybe some bug with tags inside label element.. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`float:left` to the image may solve it.

Comment: Not really. 1) The images goes to the left of the input and 2) it goes on new line even if it floats.

Answer (score 0):

In line alignment Resolved: http://jsfiddle.net/CCEn2/6/

Changes made:
In CSS: removed - "display:block;" for "span.error"

```
span.error{ color: #ac3b2a; font-style: italic; }
```

In JS: added the image inside  tag

```
$(this).parent().append("<span class='error'><img class='error' src='css/img/cross.png' alt='error' />Input non valido.</span>");
```

I hope your query was about inline alignment?

Comment: Sorry but I wanted the img on the right and the span on a new line. Thanks for helping anyway! Now I'm ok : )